# Twisting an exact sequence of sheaf gives an exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Reading through Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, and reading different notes about cohomology of sheaves, I have often seen the argument that if you have an exact sequence of coherent sheaves over a projective scheme $X$ $$0\to \mathcal{F}'\to\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}''\to 0$$ then $$0\to\mathcal{F}'(n)\to\mathcal{F}(n)\to\mathcal{F}''(n)\to 0$$ is again an exact sequence.

Is this true always? And why is this true?

Comment: Locally free sheaves are flat. You can check this on stalks, and there all I'm saying is that if $A$ is a ring then any free module $A^{\oplus I}$ is free over $A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tensoring by an invertible object (in this case $\mathcal{O}(n)$) is an equivalence of categories, and equivalences of categories preserve all limits and colimits, and in particular preserve exact sequences.